# Output array of tags while constructing anchor around them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Okay, here's what I'm trying to do. I get a return from Tumblr of my posts, 5 at a time. I already have a loop that goes through the posts and constructs them using the return's content. I'm starting to make a tag section for each post, and I'm running into some issues. I apparently don't fully understand what's needed. Here's what my steps should be:

1. Go through the array of tags that comes back and change all spaces to dashes. Add the changed tag to a new array.
2. Construct an anchor that uses the new array's tag to make a link.
3. Use the original tag array to show the tag in the text part of the anchor.

Here's what I've come up with so far, but I'm sure I did something wrong as it doesn't work.

```
    if (data.response.posts[i].tags.length != 0
                for (j=0; j <= data.response.posts[i].tags.length; j++){
                    replace(/ /g,"-");
                    tagLinks.push(data.response.posts[i].tags[j]);
                    $('#tags').append(
                        '<a href="http://www.nevermorestudiosonline.com/tagsearch.php?' + tagLinks[j] + '">' + data.response.posts[i].tags[j] + '</a>'
                    );
                };
            };
```

i is the iterator variable for the posts (since I grab 5 at a time with the API call). j is the iterator for the tag array. Am I at least close? The console keeps reporting an unexpected token after the line the FOR loop starts on. My intention for the anchor construction is to pull the URL variable and perform a tag-based API search. That I can tackle some other time though. Any help is greatly appreciated.

--
EDIT:
Okay, so now it looks like this:

```
    if (data.response.posts[i].tags.length != 0){
                for (j=0; j <= data.response.posts[i].tags.length; j++){
                    var dashedTag = data.response.posts[i].tags[j].replace(/ /g,"-");
                    tagLinks.push(dashedTag);
                    $('#tags').append(
                        '<a href="http://www.nevermorestudiosonline.com/tagsearch.php?' + tagLinks[j] + '">' + data.response.posts[i].tags[j] + '</a>'
                    );
                };
            };
```

The console tells me that it "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined." I've looked into the format, and other examples, but can't see anything wrong. What am I missing now?

Comment: you need to call replace on a string, `var dashedTag = data.response.posts[i].tags[j].replace(/ /g, '-');`

Comment: You need to tell the JS what to do the `replace(/ /g, "-");` on

Comment: Okay, I follow that. Am I pushing to the new array correctly? Would I need to do tagLinks.push(dashedTag[j]); ?
I haven't done a lot with arrays and they throw me off. >.<

Comment: WOW. I just noticed I didn't properly open my if statement. >.< I was missing the ){ to start it off. >.<

Comment: `j < data.response.posts[i].tags.length` length is always one more than the last valid list index

Comment: Shouldn't that be caught by the fact I'm using <= ?

Comment: `<=` is "less than or equal to" and if `j` is equal to `length` then it's one more than the largest valid index, so it's not a valid index.